# Android does not accept root CA certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate

I have an android app that talk to my internal server with https. The server uses a certificate from my companies' root CA. I have installed the root certificate in my store. When I access the API on my Windows machine the certificate is shown as valid.

I don't want to disable the certificate validation and I don't want to abstain from using SSL.

The error I receive is: **Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify network security config by a reference from your application's block in the manifest. [Check it out](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html).

If I remember well, starting from Android N it became necessary to specify trusted certificates groups explicitly in manifest.

Windows just trusts all certificates that through a chain of trust point to any root trusted certificate. Android has it's own opinion about that.

Comment: The network security config requires and Android 7.0 (API level 24) device or newer to work.

Comment: @Robert, it gives an error or just a warning that it is pointless and better to override the manifest for v24? If here is the last case, then we can work with it. This security config worked for me when I had overriden exactly general network config (not the debug one) and defined that I trust either user and system certificates. I don't have any clue why it didn't work for debug-network-config or with just user certificates trust. Last statement can be explained someway by me, but not the first one